# How to change the border color of a GeometryDrawing in wpf

Tags: wpf, geometrydrawing

I have some WPF code binding a block to a color as follows:

```
    <GeometryDrawing>
        <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="{Binding Path=Element.Color}"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.00" Color="{Binding Path=Element.Color}"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
    </GeometryDrawing>
```

Now I want to bind the border (or Pen property) to another field, such as Element.BorderColor.  How should that be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ElementName binding to bind to properties in other UI elements in your window

```
<GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="{Binding ElementName=MyElement Path=TheColor}"/>
```